# Image Moderation always times out on Google Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to implement an image moderation function on my flutter app, and I'm using this function as a starting point:

[Image Moderation on Github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/moderate-images/functions/index.js)

Unfortunately, even though the function detects images that need to be moderated, the ImageMagick blur function **always times out**.

I've added additional timeout - up to 60 seconds (which seems a very long period for images no bigger than 400x400!) - but to no avail.

Am I missing something? I'm on a Blaze plan, so should have no issue from a capacity perspective, but I just can't seem to get the blurred image out of the function?

**EDIT:** seems to be the `await mkdirp(tempLocalDir);` which is causing the problem. From the Github code, everything works up to that point...?

Comment: What does `tempLocalDir` look like? Have you tried logging the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to not create temp local directories and simply download the file to `/tmp` and clean up afterwards. Since functions run in isolation, you are not going to encounter name collisions.

Comment: Yup, that about did it. Have to abandon the making of a custom temp directory and just use the os.tempdir(). Seems that Firebase Storage won't allow you to make custom folders beyond this one, so if you ever need to do anything with a function spawned folder, it'll always need to be in /tmp.

Thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Cloud Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system):

> the only writable folder in Cloud Function instance is /temp folder and The rest of the file system is read-only and accessible to the function.

Note that writing to /temp folder will consume memory resources provisioned for the function.